# Ubuntu not booting after updating to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, kernel

I'm using Ubuntu for a few months, installed on a laptop where I also have win7, but there are different installations, different drives. Today I've tried my first Ubuntu upgrade, from 12.04 to 12.10
Everything was ok, and after cleaning old files, the upgrade manager asked for a restart. After the restart I got this on a blank screen:

```
GRUB4DOS 0.4.5b 2011-11-27, Mem: 628k/2485M, End: 35560D

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word,TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else tab lists the
possible completions of a device/filename.

grub>
```

And after typing boot I got this error:

```
Error 8: Kernel must be loaded before booting
```

I must say that I enjoy Ubuntu as OS, but I'm not such a technical guy, so any help is welcome. Thank you very much!

Comment: Close voters:  The OP has solved this problem in an answer.  There is no need to close this.

Answer (score 2):

Done, guys. 
I've downloaded and used boot-repair-disk.iso.
Now I'm back on my Ubuntu